# PHP split time string

Tags: php, string, date, split

How can I split this string `2014.11.30, 21:05` to get 5 other strings?

After that, I want to convert them to `int` to be able to do some calculations.

For e.g.:

```
y = 2014
m = 11
d = 30
h = 21
min = 05
```

Comment: anyone? i try use preg_match, but i didn't know how to config this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` to convert it to a time stamp, then `date()` to extract each of those variables.

Or you can use `preg_match()` with a regex like:

```
/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+), ([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/
```

Which will give you an array of those values.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following function without using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
<?php
$date = '2014.11.30, 21:05';

function extract_date($d){
$first = explode(".", $d);
$second = explode(", ", $first[2]);
$third = explode(":", $second[1]);

$res['y'] = (int)$first[0];
$res['m'] = (int)$first[1];
$res['d'] = (int)$second[0];
$res['h'] = (int)$third[0];
$res['min'] = (int)$third[1];
return $res;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(extract_date($date));
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://codepad.org/7gvs57is